# How to resolve this error : RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 1362420 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.`

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, deeplearning4j, style-transfer

I tried to execute loho.py
and I got this error

'''This is the error msg :
Setting up Perceptual loss... Loading model from: /content/LOHO/networks/lpips/weights/v0.1/vgg.pth ...[net-lin [vgg]] initialized ...Done Setting up Perceptual loss... Loading model from: /content/LOHO/networks/lpips/weights/v0.1/vgg.pth ...[net-lin [vgg]] initialized ...Done Constructing DeepLabv3+ model... Number of classes: 20 Output stride: 16 Number of Input Channels: 3 /content/drive/MyDrive/inference.pth Traceback (most recent call last): File "/content/LOHO/loho.py", line 180, in 
state_dict = torch.load(graphonomy_model_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 595, in load return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 781, in _legacy_load deserialized_objects[key]._set_from_file(f, offset, f_should_read_directly)
RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 1362420 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.
'''

Trying to run this repo : GitHub - https://github.com/saakshi077/LOHO.

Colab File link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ykZK0v81l20UnbFDhr1P6PH54gFGhBqV?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add the complete command you ran for executing loho.py?

Comment: This 
!python /content/LOHO/loho.py

Comment: Shouldn't image flag be passed?